# How can I use coffeescript within a underscore.js template

Tags: coffeescript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am using underscore.js templates, and have certain **if** conditions embedded within template. I would like to use coffeescript within the template.

```
<% if (app.user.get("id") != -1 or app.user.get("product")?.name != "Foo") {%> 
   do-stuff
<% } %>
```

Above won't work, I have to use javascript instead of coffee.

Is there a way to get this done, other than using any further third party libraries like haml-coffee?

Answer (score 0):

Nope if you're working in that environment it'll have to be native js. You could however, do some of the work in a coffee script file that returns an html template instead.

Comment: [this may help](http://blog.jrmoran.com/underscorejs-templates-with-haml-and-coffeesc/) 
I know you said you'd rather not do the 3rd-party library route, but I don't there's any other way.